# Confirmar reenvio do formulário ERR_CACHE_MISS ao voltar para página anterior?

Tags: php, javascript, cakephp, navegador-de-internet

Pessoal após eu preencher um formulário e enviar para o banco de dados via `POST`, e após isso seguir para outra página, quando volto a este formulário pelo navegador "`<-`" ocorre este erro na tela: "Confirmar reenvio do formulário `ERR_CACHE_MISS`" alguém sabe o que pode ser e como ajustar isso?

Comment: Esse erro aparece só no console? Olha isso: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26408931/bizarre-error-in-chrome-developer-console-failed-to-load-resource-neterr-ca