# Como soluciono o ERR_CACHE_MISS php?

Tags: php, cache

Sempre que eu clico em retornar na navegação do browser aparece a mensagem para confirmar o reenvio do formulário e o erro: ERR_CACHE_MISS.

Como faço para que ao clicar para retornar na página anterior ele não peça essa confirmação?

Já tentei colocar no `header`:

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" content="no-cache"> 
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" content="-1">
```

mas não funcionou, alguma dica?

Comment: Duplicata https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/64505/3635?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento vamo ver se chega a 265^ essa questão tmb..;)

Comment: MagicHat que? ...

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/64505/confirmar-reenvio-do-formulário-err-cache-miss-ao-voltar-para-página-anterior#comments-64505 x)

Comment: Continua sem sentido :/

Comment: Xesuis... Clica no link se vai ver um pergunta com 261^ up votes, "vamo ver se chega a 265^ essa questão tmb..;) " @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: Não, você não entendeu, SOen é um site e SOpt é outro, em nenhum momento coloquei em evidencia o link para o SOen, só falei que já existe uma pergunta no SO**pt** sobre o assunto, ou seja duplicata, não concorda?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62860/discussion-between-magichat-and-guilherme-nascimento).

Answer (score 2):

Isso não tem relação com PHP. É o comportamento padrão do browser.

Quando uma página submete dados pelo método POST, esses dados precisam ser submetidos novamente ao retroceder a navegação. Se for cancelada a submissão, o browser exibe mensagens como essa abaixo:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Chrome browser.